# how to find the unique values in integer in python like categories?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

RangeIndex: 559 entries, 0 to 558
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------            --------------  -----
 0   Film              559 non-null    category
 1   Genre             559 non-null    category
 2   CriticsRating     559 non-null    int64
 3   AudienceRatings   559 non-null    int64
 4   BudgetInMillions  559 non-null    int64
 5   Year              559 non-null    category

to find unique value in category I can use the following code 
'details.Genre.cat.categories'

how to find the unique values in int64